# Repackage a jar file that had a bunch of dependencies

Tags: java

I have a jar file that I wish to repackage its dependencies.

But I do not have the source code of that jar.

Is there a tool that I can use to repackage its dependencies?

What Should I use?

THanks

Comment: What do you mean by *repackage*? Is it to try to get which jar does your jar file depends on to be used?

Comment: jar is just a package, u can "un-package" them and remove/add further classes to it

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Packing/repacking a jar doesn't depend on source code; a jar's contents are a jar's contents. Open it up and do whatever you want to it.

Comment: My jar had a bunch of internal dependencies. Some of these dependencies are conflicting with my own. I wish to repackage it in a way so that these dependencies are no longer in the same name space as my own dependency. How do I achieve that?

Comment: By internal dependencies, you mean classes, right? If that's the case you can just remove them from the file.

Comment: @GonzaloMatheu Yes. Classes inside some package. But they are using a different version. How can I be sure that using my version won't break it?

Comment: Using unit tests or during runtime.

Comment: Instead is there a way to rename the dependencies of that jar? So that I know for sure it will work. Or fail. At least consistently as how the writer of that jar expects.